# how to trigger data-action on element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to do dynamic select fields and I succeded based on gorails video tutorial.

I have this code within form, which is working fine:

```
<%= form.select :repository, Github.new.repos(), {}, { data: { action: "change->select#change" }} %>
```

which, on selection triggers the `change->select#change` which resides in select_controller.js

however, when I use web-component the data-action is not triggered at all, even if the generated code is the same...

```
<cds-elect
    value=""
    name="metadatum[repository]"
    id="metadatum_repository"
    title-text="repository"
    data-action="change-&gt;select#change"
    >
<cds-select-item value="repo1">repo1</cds-select-item>
<cds-select-item value="repo2">repo2</cds-select-item>
</cds-select>
```

what I am missing in my code in order to trigger data-action? or how to trigger it with js? I have no clue. Thank you.

I searched the internet by I am probably missing something, I am new to rails. chatgpt did not return anything meaning full.